# How do I type in special characters in Cinnamon with various apps?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, special-characters

I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux Daedalus, with Cinnamon 5.6.7 (Xorg server 21.1.7).

I want to type in some characters not available on my keyboard, nor (to my knowledge) in my keyboard layout (English - English (US); and also sometimes Hebrew - Hebrew). I know I can get them using the charmap application, but I'd really rather type and not use the mouse, switch focus etc.

Can I do this? How?

Notes:

- I use all kinds of apps, but for the sake of discussion let's focus on entering text in text areas/boxes in Nemo (the file explorer), cinnamon dialog boxes, text editors like gedit and mousepad, and Firefox text areas/boxes.
- I'm most interested in Latin-ish characters from the "Latin Supplementary" Unicode block, such as: §, ±, · and others; so if your answer only regards those it's still valid.